# Referencing viewContext using a static var to implement Core Data for both iOS 9 and iOS 10 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm just learning Core Data and I need to implement Core Datafor both iOS 9 and iOS 10 as my only iPad test device is an iPad3 running iOS 9.3.5. I tried to follow other solutions here in stack overflow but I don't find a specific answer to my case. I'm trying to follow this solution

> https://charleswilson.blog/2016/09/09/out-of-context-using-core-data-on-ios-9-3-and-10-0/

I normally reference `viewContext` using a `static var` as

```
static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer
    }
    static var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
```

I can't find a way to reference for `iOS10`and `iOS9`. Im writing them now as :

// persistent container

```
static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
     if #available(iOS 10.0,*){
    return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer
} else {
// what context to return here for iOS 9?
}
}


//  context
static var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if #available(iOS 10.0,*){
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    } else {
        return // what context to return here for iOS 9?
    }
}
```

but I get the error : `Instance member 'databaseContext' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'`.
Also because I'm giving the types `: NSPersistentContainer`and `: NSManagedObjectContext`will only make the `static var`available for `iOS10`
How would write them I now to be able to reference it for `iOS10`and `iOS9` ?
Many thanks

Comment: In your implementation of `static var persistentContainer`, regarding your comment `// what context to return here for iOS 9?`, the answer is that you cannot return anything because the class `NSPersistentContainer` is not available in ios 9.  In other words, your approach here will not work.

Comment: Also, although I have not digested the entire post by Charles Wilson which you referenced, but it looks like that post is explaining how to solve exactly the problem you have.  Can you not just copy the code in that post?

Comment: @Jerry Krinock the solution propose `lazy var databaseContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {         return self.persistentContainer.viewContext     } else {         return self.managedObjectContext     } }()` to reference the right `NSManagedObjectContext` depending on the iOS version.. so that ` saveContext()` would work both ways.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to make a `static` version of that `lazy var database Context`

Comment: Well, forget the `static var persistentContainer` implementation.  As far as `static var viewContext`, in *// what context to return here for iOS 9?* what you do is build the old-fashioned Core Data stack, as in the post by Charles Wilson.  It is true that this will take several dozen lines of code, as compared to the one line `return persistentContainer.viewContext` you have for iOS 10.0+, but that's why we don't like to deploy to older systems :)

Comment: @Jerry Krinock that's the point i guess . As i'm learning Core Data i learned the new way, and i'm trying to cope with the old way out of need.

Comment: I anyways found a post on github thas seems to do exactly what i thought and the static vars ar just as i tried.. the difference is that I was doing it in `AppDelegate` while in that post they're all declared in  custom class..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bourvill/10b63311ae5a47a95f4026fe8118f913